# Build less @import url dynamically

Tags: import, less

While working on a google webfont import **mixin**, I noticed that it is not possible to build @import URLs dynamically.

```
.gFontImport (@name, @weights, @subsets) {
    @url: "http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=@{name}:@{weights}&subset=@{subsets}";
    @import url(@url);
}
```

Which can be narrowed down to

```
@url: "http://localhost/test.css";
@import url(@url);
```

Neither any of these additional tests work:

```
@import url("@{url}"); // this one renders at least

@import url(~"@{url}");
```

When the compiler renders the CSS file the @import URL is always left unchanged, e.g. `"@{url}"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to work in 1.4 beta.

### 1.4

Doing something like this (I tried it out at [less2css.org](http://less2css.org/)) in **LESS**:

```
.gFontImport (@name, @weights, @subsets) {
    @import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=@{name}:@{weights}&subset=@{subsets}');
}

.gFontImport("Roboto+Slab",400,latin);
```

will have the expected output in **CSS**:

```
@import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:400&subset=latin');
```

---

### <=1.3.3

If it does not work for you, you can use a workaround that injects the `@import` call into a selector name:

```
.gFontImport (@name, @weights, @subsets) {
    @gimport: ~"@import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=@{name}:@{weights}&subset=@{subsets}');";
    @{gimport} some-selector {/* */};
}
```

so calling something like this in **LESS**:

```
.gFontImport("Roboto+Slab",400,latin);
```

will output this in **CSS**:

```
@import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:400&subset=latin');
some-selector {
  /**/
}
```

This works, but it is a tiny bit messy. In a javascript implementation of LESS you can use

```
`'\n'`
```

and

```
`'\t'`
```

in the string interpolation to make it look a bit tidier.

Comment: Sadly the nice version gives me ```@import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=@{name}:@{weights}&subset=@{subsets}');```

Comment: The above solution does not render correctly even in less2css.org !

Comment: The latter does work. Thanks for that hack! On the other hand you want that @import for a web font to be at the very beginning of the compiled CSS file. Injecting it into a selector breaks this optimization. Now it ends up somewhere in the middle of the code and the browser will start downloading the font a little later.

Comment: I edited the answer ... it worked on LESS 1.4 for me on less2css, but then I was a bit blind, when changing the versions =)

Comment: It depends on the version of less that you use. The nice solution work s from 1.4 on. Thanks a lot @Martin

Answer (score 1):

I've made a gist with working mixins for both versions 
https://gist.github.com/line-o/5568723

Comment: Cool, I only now checked it out, Thanks for sharing it! +1 from me ^_^

Answer (score 1):

A working example, that defines font sets :
(with Less v1.7.3)

```
// Google font import mixin
.gFontImport (@name; @weights: 400; @subsets: latin) {
    @nameEsc: ~`"@{name}".replace(/'([^']+)'/,'$1').replace(' ', '+')`;
    @import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=@{nameEsc}:@{weights}&subset=@{subsets}');
}


// Font sets
// The variable @post-fontset is dynamic (user input)
// ------------------

// foo1
.font(@fontset) when (@fontset = foo1){
    .gFontImport('Roboto');
    .gFontImport('Lato');
}
.font-text() when (@post-fontset = foo1){
    font-family:Lato;
}
.font-headings() when (@post-fontset = foo1){
    font-family:Lato;
}
.font-sitetitle() when (@post-fontset = foo1){
    font-family:Roboto;
}

// foo2
.font(@fontset) when (@fontset = foo2){
    .gFontImport('Oswald');
    .gFontImport('Lato');
    .gFontImport('Roboto Slab');
}
.font-text() when (@post-fontset = foo2){
    font-family:'Roboto Slab';
}
.font-headings() when (@post-fontset = foo2){
    font-family:Lato;
}
.font-sitetitle() when (@post-fontset = foo2){
    font-family:Oswald;
}


// Using the mixins in the CSS
// ------------------

// This executes the font import mixin
.font(@post-fontset);

// Site title
h1{.font-sitetitle();}

// Heading
h2, h3, h4, h5, h6{.font-headings();}

// Text
body{.font-text();}
```